# Is there a way to get the email address of a GitHub Issue?

Tags: github

When I setup Notifications to go to my email I can reply to the email and the content of my email will get added to the GitHub Issue page.

This works because GitHub creates a Reply-To email address for each issue, which looks like reply+ABAM6J2H3WPXLLHRMBHDRGCSBNWTEVBNHHGKHQCTU@reply.github.com

Is there a way for me to get that email address from the Issue page?

I was thinking, there might be a magic URL, like https://github.com/josemvidal/sandbox/issues/123?email or somesuch, that gives us the Reply-To email for Issue 123 in that repo.

Big picture: I want an easy way to forward emails I get to specific Issues in GitHub. Right now I have to cut-n-paste email contents.

Comment: I don't think so, but depending on your mail program, you could try piping to a custom program that posts them to the API.  If there were such a place that you could see the email address for the issue, an API response would be the place I'd look for it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

..........27 more characters.......